# Featured hot question in feed sometimes repeats itself

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, ios-app-feed

I love the "Hot Network Questions" at the top of the feed in the Stack Exchange iOS app; they're almost too good at holding my attention.

While I'm aware you can click through to view a more concise list of what's hot across the networks, I often find myself thinking "I'll just pull-down-refresh to read one more question before I close the app..".

However; the random questions sometimes repeat! So when I go for 'one more' cheeky roll of the dice, sometimes I am shown a question I read moments earlier (never consecutive though I should add), forcing me to shamefully grant myself one more spin...

Perhaps the way which the questions are 'randomised' may need review?

Great app though, I've been eagerly awaiting it for years .

Screenshot of random question in my feed for clarity:

> [image]

Comment: Not sure it is a good idea. What if you misclick it, thus "losing" a question? What if you forget a hot question? I think it's good to have the questions repeat at some point, though maybe add time factor e.g. 5 minutes.

Comment: Hmm, I think that pull down refresh is a fairly deliberate interaction. Plus the user could click through and search for something if they really wanted to find it again. As you say - perhaps if questions must be repeated, they should be spaced out a little further.

Answer (score 1):

This will be added in 1.4.3 in January.

```
-        if let choices = potentialQuestions {
+        if let choices = potentialQuestions?.filter({ $0 != visibleQuestion }) {
```